# Selenium Python find_element_by_class_name

Tags: selenium

so i am trying to grab all the subreddits from reddit.coms front page, but I have only figured out how to grab 1, and it only works when I do it with the find_element_by_css_selector. I want to be able to go through the page and grab all of them, but I dont know how that would be possible with CSS selectors.

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser =webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\jacka\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\c hromedriver.exe')
browser.get("https://www.reddit.com/")

elem = browser.find_element_by_class_name('s1uc7yii-0 eAfOKg')


e = elem.text
print(e)
```

Comment: Which elements are `subreddits` exactly?

Comment: they are "a class". <a class="s1uc7yii-0 eAfOKg" data-click-id="subreddit" href="/r/PoliticalHumor/">r/PoliticalHumor</a>                       I just want to grab the "r/PoliticalHumor" part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use data-click-id="subreddit" to create cssSelector

```
a[data-click-id='subreddit']
```

Use findElements instead of findElement which retrieve all webElements related to provided cssSelector

To get href use .getAttribute("href") instead of getText.

Comment: I am a bit confused on the first part. how do i use that line in the code with css_selector? thank ou for the help, I am very new to this.

Comment: use browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[data-click-id='subreddit']");